# Android OsclNativeFile error: Seek lseek64 failed

Tags: android

I get the following error on my Android device:

> E/OsclNativeFile( 1616): OsclNativeFile::Seek lseek64 failed

I want to know what it means, because I wasn't making anything special just getting a battery drain and the logcat show me zillion lines like the above. Thanks.

Comment: i get the sam Error When i re install one of my application from Eclipse while doing this suddenly In My LogCat Show This Error

Answer (score 1):

I got the same. That happened after i had updated my LG Optimus One P500 phone to android 2.3.3. I read this topic with no answers and was a bit disappointed. I tried to come back to 2.2, but phone didn't start (it stopped at android logo). I installed 2.3.3 again and it started normally. Then i experimented and soon noticed that there was no errors with sd-card unmounted. So I removed all programs from sd-card, and deleted all files from it (I moved it to laptop). And I have no such errors now. Maybe there is an easier way to solve it, but it has worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The lseek64() system library function is typically used to access large files (2GB or greater).  It's possible there's a flaw with the way the platform implements lseek64.  A workaround--as tonixart has discovered--is to delete the large files on your sdcard.